# Can I delete app id from enterprise account and reuse it in standard developer account

Tags: ios, identifier, enterprise, account, apple-developer

Can I delete an app id from enterprise account and reuse it in standard developer account?

Please share your experiences on this and whats the impact.

Comment: It will get affected as the profiles etc are tied to the app identifier including notifications. The existing profiles may become invalid. The installed apps may not get affected but their capabilities might get affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can delete app id from one developer account and use that in another developer account. After deleting app id from your old account or in your case enterprise account you can use that in standard developer account. But if you want to use that same app id again to enterprise account you need to delete app id from standard account. Because app id are unique

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. Just transfer the app to your standard account.